# Using $in operator with other comparison operators in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm working on a project where I need to compare data from one collection to another in my Mongo database. Specifically, user preferences and vehicle data. I want to match a user's vehicle of choice to a matching vehicle in an inventory.

The question: How do I use the min year and max year I get from the user choice (a javascript object) and create a query that will match the vehicle year?

So far I've taken each user and mapped the choice arrays (picks) to category arrays (minYear, maxYear, make, model) and been successful matching make and model using the $in operator. Now, I'm confused how I might do the same thing with an array or two of possible years. I tried using $gte and $in, but... no luck.

Here's my code:

```
const inv = db.collection('inventory'), users = db.collection('users')

users.find().toArray((err, docs) => {
    if (err) throw new Error(err)
    const users = docs
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        let user = users[i],
            userId = user._id,
            picks = user.profile.picks,
            minYears = picks.map(pick => {
                return pick.minYear
            }),
            maxYears = picks.map(pick => {
                return pick.maxYear
            }),
            makes = picks.map(pick => {
                return pick.make.toUpperCase()
            }),
            models = picks.map(pick => {
                return pick.model.toUpperCase()
            }),
            yards = user.profile.yards.map(yard => {
                return yard.yard
            })

            console.log(minYears)

        inv
            .find({
                year: { $gte: { $in: minYears }, $lte: { $in: maxYears } },
                make: { $in: makes },
                model: { $in: models },
                yardName: { $in: yards }
            })
            .toArray((err, docs) => {
                if (err) throw new Error(err)
                console.log(
                    `Customer with mobile number ${user.profile.mobile} has ${docs.length} matches.`)
            })
    }
```

And this is what my user array looks like:

```
[
    user1: {
        id,
        profile: {
            picks: [
                { minYear, maxYear, make, model },
                { minYear, maxYear, make, model },
                { minYear, maxYear, make, model }
            ],
            yards: [
                { yardName1, yardName2, yardName3 }
            ]
        }
    },
    user2: {
        id,
        profile: {
            picks: [
                { minYear, maxYear, make, model },
                { minYear, maxYear, make, model }
            ],
            yards: [
                { yardName1, yardName2 }
            ] 
        }
    }
]
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Why do you have multiple options for the minYear and maxYear?

Comment: So, the script is running through each user, who each has multiple vehicle choices. `[ user1: { [ car1: {minYear, maxYear, make, model }, car2: {...}, user2: { [ car1: {...}, car2: {...} ] ]`    Make sense?

Comment: So you have a single value for the minYear and one for maxYear. So it seems you can use something like: `year: {'$gt': minYear, '$lt': maxYear}`

Comment: Yeah, but I have to iterate through all of their choices as well. I tried nested for loops, but mongo got angry with me.

Comment: I added a model of the user array to my original question. Hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: Looks like you mean `$or` here. What you probably do not realize is that a statement like `"year":  { "$gt": minYear, "$lt": "maxyear" }` is actually a "shorthand" version of `$and` applied to the same property. As such `$in` is "shorthand" for `$or` as applied to the same property. Therefore you need the expansion because it's actually an `$or` of `$and`'s and not the other way around. Also `$gt` and `$lt` are operators and not "properties". Hence the syntax problem.

Comment: So instead. `.map()` the `$or`. As `find({ "$or": user.profile.picks.map( p => ({ "year": { "$gt": p.minYear, "$lt": p.maxYear" } }) ), make: { "$in": makes }, model: { "$in": models }, yardName: { "$in": yards }  })`

Comment: You just blew my mind! For some reason (I'm new), I didn't realize that I could just smash javascript code into the `db.coll.update()` objects. The more you know! Do you want to write up an answer for this so that I can accept it?